# Azure App Service Docker Linux Deployment - Where are my files?

Tags: bash, azure, docker, applicationservice

I have a Azure CI pipeline, that deploys .NET Core API to a Linux docker image and pushes it to our Azure Container Registry. The files are deployed to /var/lib/mycompany/app using docker-compose and dockerfile. This is then used as an image for an App Service which provides our API. The app starts fine and works, but if I go to advanced tools in the app service and run a bash session, I can see all the logs files generated by docker, but I can't see any of the files I deployed in the locations I deployed them. Why is this, and where can I find them? Is it an additional volume somewhere, a symbolic link, a layer in docker I need to access by some mechanism, a host of some sort, or black magic?

Apologies for my ignorance.

All the best,

Stu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a bash session using the Advanced Tools will open the session in the underlying VM running your container. If you want to reach your container, you need to install an ssh server in it and use the SSH tab in the Advanced Tools or the Azure CLI.

[image]

```
az webapp create-remote-connection --subscription <subscription-id> --resource-group <resource-group-name> -n <app-name> &
```

[How to configure your container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh)

[How to open an SSH session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session)

Comment: Excellent. I get it. Thanks! Will let you know hos I get on.